# Angular style.display not working as intended

Tags: angular

I am trying to show and hide drop down based on a checkbox but it's not working...

```
<p-checkbox class="column is-full" [formControlName]="'isBigCompany'" [binary]="true" [label]="'Big Company?'"></p-checkbox>

<div class="column is-full" [style.display]="companyForm.isBigCompany ? 'block' : 'none'">Is Big Company</div>
<p-dropdown class="column" [options]="bigCompanies" [formControlName]="'bigCompanies'" [placeholder]="'Select a Big Company'" [style]="{'width':'50%'}">
</p-dropdown>
```

i think the problem is here, but not sure how to fix it

```
[style.display]="companyForm.isBigCompany ? 'block' : 'none'"
```

I am using angular 4.3, and don't want to use ng-if

Comment: use [ngClass] instead if it not working

Comment: @PalakJadav how can i use form variables in mark up

Comment: how you create `companyForm`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the following.

Bind the `checkbox` in question two-way using `[(ngModel)]`.

`<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" [(ngModel)]="checkBoxControl" name="checkBox">`

Now, in the HTML div element, add `ngClass` attribute directive, in the following way.

`<div [ngClass]="hideOrShow()"></div>`

In your component.ts file,

```
hideOrShow() {
 var displayClass;

 if(this.checkBoxControl === value) {
  displayClass = {
    'display-div': true
   }
 }
 else {
  displayClass = {
   'hide-div': true
  }
 }
 return displayClass;
}
```

In your component.css,

Create two CSS classes by the name `display-div` & `hide-div` having properties `display: block` & `display: none` respectively.

Please note, you need to compare the value of the variable `checkboxControl` with the value, the checkbox contains when marked.

Answer (score 0):

you can use form control value as follow

```
[style.display]="companyForm?.value['isBigCompany'] ? 'block' : 'none'"
```

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-prime-dropdown?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

reactive forms aren't objects like you're trying to do here, they're forms... you could do this...

```
[style.display]="companyForm.get('isBigCompany').value ? 'block' : 'none'"
```

or I think this would work to....

```
[style.display]="companyForm.value?.isBigCompany ? 'block' : 'none'"
```